# SQL Multiple Foreign Keys as Primary Keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

If I declare the table below does it implicitly imply that both the foreign keys make a unique primary key or do I need to do something more to make both attributes as a primary key?

```
CREATE TABLE Report_has_Items
(
    ReportID int REFERENCES Report(ReportID) NOT NULL,
    ItemID int REFERENCES Item(ItemID) NOT NULL
)
```

Essentially both attributes which are foreign keys from other tables, together would form a unique key.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No it doesn't. The above table has no primary key. If you want to use the fields as a primary key use:

```
CREATE TABLE Report_has_Items(
    ReportID int REFERENCES Report(ReportID) NOT NULL,
    ItemID int REFERENCES Item(ItemID) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ReportID, ItemID)
)
```

or something similar depending on your sql dilect.

Answer (score 9):

Let's name our constraints, eh?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Report_has_Items(
    ReportID int NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT [FK_RHI_Report] (ReportId) REFERENCES dbo.Report(ReportID),
    ItemID int NOT NULL,
       Constraint [FK_RHI_Item] (ItemId) REFERENCES dbo.Item(ItemID),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_RHI] PRIMARY KEY (ReportID, ItemID)
)
```

Comment: What is the benefit of naming a constraint?

Comment: @Kairan - One main benefit is, if a query (insert, update, delete) violates a constraint, an error message will be generated with the constraint name. If the constraint name is clear and descriptive, the error message will be easier to understand; if the constraint name is a random it would be less clear.

Comment: The main reason for me is consistency across environments. I'm a support DBA. Part of that job is migrating changes from DEV to QA to PROD. I use a schema comparison tool for this. It's nice if the constraints are named the same so that differences in naming aren't flagged as differences.

Comment: @Gayu Thanks for the information.  Going forward I think I will do this.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure i understand your question completely but i assume you are trying to create a composite primary key (primary key with more than one attribute). You could do the following.

```
CREATE TABLE Report_has_Items(
  ReportID int references Report(ReportID),
  ItemID int references Item(ItemID),
  PRIMARY KEY (ReportID , ItemID )
);
```

**Note**:The pair (ReportID , ItemID ) must then be unique for the table and neither value can be NULL.

[Here is a very useful link for SQL Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)